# Bundle install doesn't work - Rubymine - (Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am doing a project in Rubymine and I get a notice that I need to install some gems. When I do the bundle install I get the following error:

> Gem::InstallError: activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2. An
>   error occurred while installing activesupport (5.1.0), and Bundler
>   cannot continue. 
>   Make sure that `gem install activesupport -v '5.1.0'`
>   succeeds before bundling.
>
> Process finished with exit code 5

I am using version 2.4.0 of Ruby, so I do not understand why I get this error.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

First check your ruby version.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
```

Use the Ruby 2.4 version instead...

```
rvm install 2.4
rvm use 2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Rubymine has nothing to do with this.

As **@Sunny** commented out you need to make sure the ruby version you are using. I recommend you to create a new file on the app root directory, name it `.ruby-version` and inside add the ruby version you want `ruby-2.4.0` (you can always modify it later and set a different versions).

Also you might want to use a ruby version manager like `rvm` or `rbenv` both are good, on my personal preference I use `rbenv` for development and `rvm` for production environments. You can follow [this guide](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/17.04), feel free to change the **OS** and the **ruby manager** as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I updated my Ruby version to the latest 3.2.2, the latest available (presently). Use "rbenv install --l" to check for the latest version.

`brew install rbenv ruby-build
rbenv init
eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"
rbenv install --l
rbenv install 3.2.2
rbenv global 3.2.2
'